# How to fix Objects are not valid as a React child error in next JS 13 and Next Auth?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next-auth

I'm building an app using next JS 13 with firebase and Next auth. after i implement firebase to Next Auth and use the session it throws an error.

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

when i console log the session it's value return as expected and even when i use the image attribute, it displays the image. but it throws this error many times. and i don't know what the problem is?

what i did is, in my `page.jsx` i imported the session like so.

```
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";
```

afterwards

```
const { data: session } = useSession([]);
console.log(session);
```

the console return is

```
{user: {…}, expires: '2023-02-14T10:09:58.384Z'}
```

user return

```
user:
  email: "mohammedbekele87@gmail.com"
  image: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AEdFTp7e3CC9nfTaGDkKD-mebf-wxL6qZKyf70jArUw5=s96-c"
  name: "Mohammed Bekele"
```

can anyone help me out?

Comment: are you passing `{user}` to jsx?

Comment: not like that, i'm console logging the data

Comment: your jsx is causign error but you are not showing any jsx code

Comment: i actually found the problem when u pointed out the `{user}`. i was using `signIn()` to JSX. now it works

Comment: but if you help me on other problem related to this it would be greate.

Comment: do u know how to prevent the glitch of Next Auth during refresh?

Comment: you should ask another question regarding the glitch with clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an async/await syntax to handle the promise like this:

```
  import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"; 

    export default async function test() {
        const { data: session } = useSession([]);
        const activeSession = await session;
        console.log(activeSession);
        if(activeSession) {
           // return session data
           {session.user.name}
           {session.user.email}
           <img className="" src={session.user.image} alt="" />
           console.log(session);
        } else {
           // return login page
        }
  }
```

Alternatively, you can use a .then() function like this:

```
     import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"; 
    
        const { data: session } = useSession([]);
        session.then(session => {
          console.log(session);
          if(session) {
             // return session data
             {session.user.name}
             {session.user.email}
             <img className="" src={session.user.image} alt="" />
          } else {
            // render the component for unauthenticated user
          }
        });
```

Comment: hey i tried both methods, for the first one i can't use await on this type. `await' has no effect on the type of this expression`. on the second it throws `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')`